# Find key by value in JS object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following piece of code:

```
var search_value = 'XYZ';
var FIELD_MAP = {
    'key1': [
        'SOME',
        'THING'
    ],
    'key2': [
        'ANOTHER_VALUE',
        'XYZ'
    ]
};
```

I need to find which array (key1, key2 etc) has a value stored in variable search_value. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by iterating over the properties of FIELD_MAP and checking if the required search string is available in any of them:

```
for (var key in FIELD_MAP) {
  if (FIELD_MAP.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

    if (FIELD_MAP[key].indexOf(search_value) > 0) {
      console.log("Found in=",key)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way by filtering keys on `FIELD_MAP` object by checking if the value contains the `search_value` by using `Object.keys` to get keys and `Array.filter` to filter them.

```
var key = Object.keys(FIELD_MAP).filter(function(k){
    return ~FIELD_MAP[k].indexOf(search_value);
})[0]; // remove the [0] if you want multiple keys matching the criteria
```